# Adding new line in between string [Angular JS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, newline, trim

I am working on a angular application. in one of the scenario when user try to change password i have a service call which will return multiple error messages in a single response for unsuccessful password change. The response is something like below.

*Password should meet the policy. Previous password can not be reused. Both New and Confirm passwords should match. Password is too short.*

How can i add a new line after each of the full stop(.) so that i can display the error messages in new lines rather than displaying it together.

**JS Code**

```
function (errorData) {
    $ctrl.errorMessage = errorData.data.error;
        $mdToast.show(
            $mdToast.simple()
                .textContent($ctrl.errorMessage)                       
                .hideDelay(3000)
            );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
  $mdToastProvider.addPreset('testPreset', {
      options: function() {
        return {
          template:
            '<md-toast>' +
              '<div class="md-toast-content">' +
                'This is a custom preset' +
              '</div>' +
            '</md-toast>',
          controllerAs: 'toast',
          bindToController: true
        };
      }
    });

    $mdToast.show(
      $mdToast.testPreset()
    );
```

for more info https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdToast